# How to add header to URI

Tags: spring, http, junit, http-headers, uri

I am doing unit test and I need to add header to my url:

```
@Test
public void getData() throws URISyntaxException, Exception{

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/data?id=sampleID";
    URI uri = new URI(baseUrl);
    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class);

    //Verify request succeed
    Assert.assertEquals(200, result.getStatusCodeValue());
    Assert.assertEquals(true, result.getBody().contains("sampleName"));

}
```

I am getting "400 null" response and I believe it's because I am missing header, I am passing header through postman and it is working fine.

How do I pass header?

UPDATE: Eamon Scullion provided link. It solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP get with headers using RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781680/http-get-with-headers-using-resttemplate)

Comment: @EamonScullion you nailed it! thanks!