# How to pass header values using RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, resttemplate

I am new to Spring. A project of mine needs to call an Autotask API which takes Api integration code, username and secret (password) in the headers. How do I integrate that into the Rest Template?

Below is a screenshot of the API that I am testing on swagger. [Screenshot of API Call using Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zfuf.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional parameters you need to send are all headers. You can set the headers as follows:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("ApiIntegrationCode", "HUCXSL...");
headers.set("UserName", "fdfsk...");
headers.set("Secret", "yR*42...");
```

Then you add the headers to a new `HttpEntity` instance and perform the request using `RestTemplate`:

```
HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

A very similar question has been asked here: [HTTP get with headers using RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781680/http-get-with-headers-using-resttemplate).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your solution works but now I am stuck on another error. Kindly take alook into it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68253983/500-internal-server-error-errorsunexpected-character-encountered-while-p