# 500 Internal Server Error: [{"errors":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: %. Path '', line 0, position 0."]}]

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, resttemplate, swagger-2.0, spring-resttemplate

I am using RestTemplate to call an AutoTask API. However I am getting an error that says: 500 Internal Server Error: [{"errors":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: %. Path '', line 0, position 0."]}]

[Swagger UI screenshot of the API call (Successful)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2sgZ.jpg)

[Console Output (Error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izUsV.jpg)

Code:

```
@GetMapping("/all-clients")
private String getAllClients() {
    
    String COMPANIES_API_URL_Prefix = "https://webservices14.autotask.net/ATServicesRest/V1.0/Companies/query?search=";
    String COMPANIES_API_URL_Suffix = "{\"filter\":[{\"op\":\"in\",\"field\":\"CompanyType\",\"value\":[1]}]}";
    
     try {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            headers.set("ApiIntegrationCode", "HUCXSL....."); //values partially hidden as it is sensitive information
            headers.set("UserName", "fdfsf...."); //values partially hidden as it is sensitive information
            headers.set("Secret", "yR*42......"); //values partially hidden as it is sensitive information

            HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
           
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            
            String url = COMPANIES_API_URL_Prefix+URLEncoder.encode(COMPANIES_API_URL_Suffix);
            
            
            System.out.println(entity);
            
            System.out.println(url);
            
            ResponseEntity<Company[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Company[].class);
            
            System.out.println("Result - status ("+ response.getStatusCode() + ") has body: " + response.hasBody());
        }
     
        catch (Exception exception) {
            
            System.out.println("** Exception: "+ exception.getMessage());
        }
     
     return "all_clients";
}
```

Comment: Spring is probably already encoding the URL for you, resulting in the json getting double-encoded. When the endpoint decodes the query, it it still encoded, hence the error. Try skipping the call to `URLEncoder.encode`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing encoding the JSON payload also that casing the problem or try as below.
Set the JSON payload in httpEntity.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        headers.set("ApiIntegrationCode", "HUCXSL....."); //values 
partially hidden as it is sensitive information
        headers.set("UserName", "fdfsf...."); //values partially 
hidden as it is sensitive information
        headers.set("Secret", "yR*42......"); //values partially hidden as it is sensitive information

        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers, 
COMPANIES_API_URL_Suffix);;
       
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        
    String url=OMPANIES_API_URL_Prefix;

        ResponseEntity<Company[]> response = 
 restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, 
Company[].class);
```