# Best way to passing parameter to restTemplate.getForObject

Tags: java, spring, code-cleanup

in order to write a clean and smart code, I'm wondering what can I do to improve my actual piece of code:

```
public JSONObject getCustomer(final String customerId) {
    if (customerId == null || customerId.equals("")) {
        return null;
    } else {
        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final String result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:6061/customers/" + customerId,
                String.class);
        return new JSONObject(result);
    }
}
```

Especially, I didn't like the way I composed the url, neither the check on customerId's value.

I'd like to have something like `JPA`, where I ask some information passing a parameter, just to be clear (in pseudocode):

```
public JSONObject getCustomer(final String customerId) {
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    final Query query = restTemplate.query("http://localhost:6061/customers/:customerId");

    query.addParameter("customerId", customerId);
    JSONObject result = query.getForObject();

    return result;
}
```

Then, if `customerId` would be `null` or some white spaces or not existing, I'd like that result would be `null`.
Is there a way to do this with a standard library?

Thanks

Comment: Best way you say? See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53544842/255139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I would remove the `else` branch and refactor the condition to:

```
public JSONObject getCustomer(final String customerId) {
    if (isNull(customerId) || customerId.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

Second, if you have a bunch of URI variables, [Spring guys recommend](https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate) using a `Map<String, String>`:

```
final String templateURL = "http://localhost:6061/customers/{customerId}";
final Map<String, String> variables = new HashMap<>();

variables.put("customerId", customerId);
...

template.getForObject(templateURL, String.class, variables);
```

Third, the method shouldn't create a `RestTemplate` instance on its own. I would prefer injecting the already-tuned object into an instance field:

```
getTemplate().getForObject(templateURL, String.class, variables);
```

Finally, I would name the `result` more meaningful:

```
final String customerRepresentation = ...;
```

---

Some notes:

1. `getCustomer` actually returns a `JSONObject`, not a `Customer`.
2. `templateURL` hardcoded the base URL as well as the URL to customers.
3. The method does a lot of work (takes too much responsibility) - argument validation, URL construction, making a request. Try to split these responsibilities between corresponding methods.

Comment: This: `template.getForObject(templateURL, String.class, variables);` is what I was looking for... thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would rather use DTO objects to hold the response data and manipulate them rather than using a String representation of the payload. So you may change it like this. Here Jackson takes care of all the serialization and deserialization of your data.

```
CustomerDTO customerDTO = restTemplate
                    .getForEntity("http://localhost:6061/customers/{customerId}", CustomerDTO.class, customerId).getBody();
```

You can use javax.validators such as `@Min`, `@NotEmpty` etc at your controller to check for the empty values. A sample  is given below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = someURL, params = {"id"})
public SomeResponse doSomething(@PathVariable(value = "id") @Size(min=1) String id)
```

This throws a `ValidationException` with a relevant error message which can be customized by you. You then need to have an error handling aspect that sets the error message in `ErrorDTO` object and set the status code appropriately.