# Required String not present : Spring Rest Template

Tags: rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to consume a (GET) rest service.

```
http://localhost:7010/abc/status?configFilePath=config%2Fconfig.properties
```

I am trying to use that using the Spring RestTemplate service

Below is the code which I have used for the restTemplate:

```
String configFile = "config/config.properties";
Map<String,String> restvars = new HashMap<String,String>();
restvars.put("configFilePath", configFile);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String restUrl = http://localhost:7010/abc/status?          
String restCall = restTemplate.getForObject(restUrl, String.class, restvars);
System.out.println(restCall.toString());
```

It throws

```
Required String parameter 'configFilePath' is not present
```

Doesn't the Map actually pass the parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at it from wrong angle. The answer from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297215/spring-resttemplate-get-with-parameters) question helped.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
        .queryParam("configFilePath", configFile);

HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(),String.class);
```