# REST API Query with a parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to query a server that looks like this:

### Server Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/query_user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String queryUser(@RequestParam(value="userId", defaultValue="-1") String userId)
{
    int id = Integer.parseInt(userId);
    User user = this.service.getUser(id);
    ...
    return userJson;
}
```

This method works when I test with **PostMan**

### Client Code

```
private synchronized void callServer(int id)
{
     final String URI = "http://localhost:8081/query_user";
     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
     MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
     map.add("userId", id);

     restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
            .add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

     // Modified to use getForEntity but still this is not working.
     ResponseEntity<String> response 
          = restTemplate.getForEntity(URI, String.class, map); 
}
```

How can I fix this? It is important that I receive the `userJson` from the Server side.

---

### EDIT

After changing to `getForEntity()` method I keep getting the `defaultValue` of `-1` on the server side. There must be something else wrong with my code. I am definitly sending a `userId` that is NOT `-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using a `UriComponentsBuilder`.

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(URI)
        .queryParam("userId", id);
```

Essentially it is appending the parameter to the URI which is what I believe PostMan is doing (that is how I thought about it).

Reference:
https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Learn-To-Make-REST-calls-With-RestTemplate-In-Spring-Boot

Answer (score 1):

Your `queryUser()` method mapped to GET; from client you call POST `restTemplate.postForEntity`

Comment: Good catch! Could you post the entire answer for anyone who has similar question?. For example I changed the call but the parameter order is now different. Also I am getting the `defaultValue` of `-1` on the server.

Comment: The `defaultValue` for `userId` is being used. I am sending a different number than `-1`. I think I am doing something else wrong. Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try `final String URI = "http://localhost:8081/query_user?{userId}";`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It causes another `-1`.

Comment: Strange... Sorry, no more ideas this time :( Take a look here - may be it will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/25434451/4362486

Comment: Thank you! You were a tremendous help and without you I wouldn't have solved this problem. +1 for you :D