# Getting null response while consuming another microservice?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have developed 2 microservices in Spring:

- a *UI-service*
- a *Login-service*, which also has UI (html-form) for testing

The *UI-service* is consuming the *Login-service*.

#### *UI-service* (code)

```
@RequestMapping("/log")
public String abc(HttpServletRequest request) {
    final String uri = "http://localhost:8093/accounts/login";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

    return result;
    //request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_LOGIN");
}


@RequestMapping("/login-user")
private String getEmployees1(HttpServletRequest request) {
    final String uri = "http://localhost:8093/login-user";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

    return result;
}
```

#### *Login-service* (code)

I have this working on port 8093.

```
@RequestMapping("/accounts/login") //login 
public String login(HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_LOGIN");
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping ("/login-user") // checking user details in database
public String loginUser(@ModelAttribute User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    if(userService.findByEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword())!=null) {
        return "index";
    }
    else {
        request.setAttribute("error", "Invalid username and password!");
        request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_LOGIN");
        return "login";
    }
}
```

I have placed following attributes `MODE_HOME` and `MODE_LOGIN` in the JSP-page.

Same code if i test with Login Service with its UI, it is working fine but while consuming from UI service it is taking `null` value. I am able to consume the service but following value is showing in the console (`console.log`) when same service is used:

```
select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.`email` as email2_0_, user0_.`fname` as fname3_0_, 
user0_.`lname` as lname4_0_, user0_.`pwd` as pwd5_0_, user0_.`phone` as phone6_0_ from user 
user0_ where user0_.`email`=? and user0_.`pwd`=?
```

But when consuming the *Login-service* from another using `restTemplate`:

```
select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.`email` as email2_0_, user0_.`fname` as fname3_0_, 
user0_.`lname` as lname4_0_, user0_.`pwd` as pwd5_0_, user0_.`phone` as phone6_0_ from user user0_ 
where (user0_.`email` is null) and (user0_.`pwd` is null)
```

I am new to this.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Your login service appears to be expecting a `User` object to exist in the request, but it doesn't look like you're sending any user information when you call the login service from your UI service.

Comment: @Jordan how can i send that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue

Your code calls the *Login-service* **without query-parameters**, just with a base-URL:

```
http://localhost:8093/login-user
```

As a result the model `User` will be created, but its fields `email` and `password` are not set (both are still `null`).

If then passing the `User` object to your SQL-query, the respective parameters are also evaluated to `null`.

Thus on the console log the resulting SQL is shown also with `null` where instead some valid values would be expected.

#### Solution

Pass needed query-parameters `email` and `password` to the call of `restTemplate.getForObject`.

Either by using Spring's `RestTemplate`'s method [`getForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType, Map<String,?> uriVariables)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-) by passing the query-parameters to `getForObject` as map:

```java
Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<>();
parameterMap.put("email", "theEmail@domain.com");
parameterMap.put("password", "secret");

restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class, parameterMap);
```

Or use Spring's [UriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) to build the complete URL (including query-parameters) and pass it like this:

```java
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(uri)
  .queryParam("email","theEmail@domain.com")
  .queryParam("password","secret")
  .build();

restTemplate.getForObject(uriComponents.toUriString(), String.class);
```

In both approaches the resulting HTTP GET will use following URL:

```
http://localhost:8093/login-user?email=theEmail@domain.com&password=secret
```

#### See also

- similar question on [using @ModelAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc)
- similar question on [using RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297215/spring-resttemplate-get-with-parameters)
- Baeldung's Java Spring Tutorial: [The Guide to UriComponentsBuilder](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-uricomponentsbuilder)
- Baeldung's Java Spring Tutorial: [The Guide to RestTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template)